# as.Date returning NA

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have this df

```
Date;count
2014-10-15;1
2014-12-01;1
2015-01-14;1
2015-03-15;1
2015-07-20;1
2015-10-15;1
2016-01-02;1
2016-01-03;1
2016-02-15;1
2016-04-15;1
```

The Date is in %Y-%m-%d format and I created another column with just month and year using the dplyr package. This new column has the correct data as character,so I added a new command to convert this column:

```
df<-df %>%
  mutate(monthyear = format(Date, "%m-%Y")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(monthyear), as.Date, format = "%m-%Y")
```

It turns out that the output of the monthyear column is NA.
I tried converting this column to factor before converting to date and NA continues.
I also tried

```
df<-df %>%
  mutate(monthyear = format(Date, "%m-%Y"))
```

and then run the commands

```
df$monthyear <- as.Date(df$monthyear, format = "%m-%Y")
```

or

```
df$monthyear <- as.Date(paste0("1/", df$monthyear), format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

In all cases my output is NA in all rows.

Answer (score 1):

It won't get converted to `Date` class unless we have all the three components i.e. day, month, and year.  When we do the `monthyear`, it loses the 'day' part.  If we need to reconvert, have to add a day

```
df %>%
  mutate(monthyear = format(Date, "%m-%Y")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(monthyear), ~ as.Date(paste0("1-", .x), format = "%d-%m-%Y")))
```